# Why is my TextView hidden below a black bar when using a WebView in Android with Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, webview

I am trying to display a WebView and with a TextView widget below the WebView. The WebView contains ordinary HTML.

When I am trying to scroll past the WebView, I can't see the TextView.

[image from layout inspector and avd](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zoLQd.png)

It shows that the TextView was hidden below a black bar.

This is the code for MainActivity:

```
package com.example.webviewtest

import android.annotation.SuppressLint
import android.os.Bundle
import android.webkit.WebView
import android.webkit.WebViewClient
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity

class MainActivity: AppCompatActivity() {

    @SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val webView = findViewById<WebView>(R.id.wbvTextParagraph)
        webView.webViewClient = WebViewClient()
        webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/text-web.html")
        webView.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
        webView.settings.setSupportZoom(true)
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/wbvTextParagraph"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/tvSample"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/wbvTextParagraph"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/wbvTextParagraph"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/wbvTextParagraph" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

text-web.html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<p>test only</p>
<p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque 
  laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi 
  architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas 
  sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione 
  voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet,
   consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et 
   dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum 
   exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi 
   consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse 
   quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla 
   pariatur?</p>
<p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque 
  laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi 
  architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas 
  sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione 
  voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet,
    consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et 
    dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum 
    exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi 
    consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse 
    quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla 
    pariatur?</p>
</body>
</html>
```

I have tried adding TextView margin and padding, it didn't work. If I delete the second

tag, I can see the TextView, but I don't want that. Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `WebView`'s height is `wrap_content`, so it will be as tall as it needs to be to display all the text you're putting in it - which in your example means it fills the screen.

Because your `TextView` is constrained to the bottom of that, it's basically being pushed off the screen. That "black bar" you're talking about is the navigation bar when you have *gesture navigation* enabled - all you need to worry about is that your `TextView` is outside of your app's display area.

---

You need to set up your constraints so all your fixed elements are where they need to be, and then things like your `WebView` can be constrained to fit the remaining space. So you need to constrain the bottom of your `TextView` to the bottom of `parent`, so it's pinned to the bottom of the screen. (And that's all that's important for its position - you don't need to constrain *it* to the `WebView` at all.)

Once you have that in place, you can constrain your `WebView` to those fixed views and let it use whatever space is between them. So the `WebView`'s *top* needs to be constrained to the top of `parent`, and its *bottom* needs to be constrained to the *top* of the `TextView`. That way, you're anchoring it between those fixed elements. And then if you set its height to `0dp`, it'll size to fit that space.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following steps to align a WebView and a TextView vertically:

1. Set the height of the WebView to "0dp" and give it a vertical weight of "1" by changing the "android:layout_height" attribute from "wrap_content" to "0dp".
2. Set the "app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf" attribute of the WebView to the ID of the TextView, so that the WebView will be positioned above the TextView.
3. Set the "app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf" attribute of the TextView to the ID of the WebView, so that the TextView will be aligned with the bottom of the WebView.

This should align the WebView and TextView vertically, and the height of the WebView will automatically adjust to fill the remaining space.